# put a ' ' around any word that has any space in it

Tags: r, regex, string, function, dataframe

I have some textual data (`dat`) in which one variable, `State`, could consist of some words and some space e.g., `New York`.

To read the data correctly, I need any **string** elements in the entire `dat` that have space in them to be placed in single quotation marks like so: `New York` --> `'New York'`.

I was wondering if this is possible to achieve?

```
dat <-
"State Expend PTratio Salary PctSAT SAT PctACT ACT
Montana 5.692 16.3 28.785 21 1009 55 21.9
New York 9.774 13.8 46.087 70 898 3 20.8
"
# EXAMPLE OF USE:
read.table(text = dat, header = T) # Error! But if we use 'New York' works fine!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is based on a pattern for the column 'State', then we can insert the `''` for the words that doesn't include digits (`\\D+`), capture as a group, followed by a space and one or more digits (`(\\d+)` - captured as a second group), in the `replacement`, specify the backreferences (`\\1`, `\\2`) of the captured group, and insert the quotes around the first capture group

```
read.table(text = gsub("\n(\\D+\\s*\\D+) (\\d+)",
           "\n'\\1' \\2", dat), header = TRUE)
#    State Expend PTratio Salary PctSAT  SAT PctACT  ACT
#1  Montana  5.692    16.3 28.785     21 1009     55 21.9
#2 New York  9.774    13.8 46.087     70  898      3 20.8
```

---

The OP mentioned if the column is a at different position.  Here we are making use of patterns i.e. if the column is at nth position and the immediate neigbours are digits, then use that to create the pattern

```
dat1 <- "Expend PTratio Salary PctSAT SAT State PctACT ACT\n5.692 16.3 28.785 21 1009 Montana 55 21.9\n 9.774 13.8 46.087 70 898 New York 3 20.8\n"
read.table(text = gsub("(\\d+)\\s+([A-Za-z ]+) (\\d+)",
         "\\1 '\\2' \\3", dat1), header = TRUE)
# Expend PTratio Salary PctSAT  SAT    State PctACT  ACT
#1  5.692    16.3 28.785     21 1009  Montana     55 21.9
#2  9.774    13.8 46.087     70  898 New York      3 20.8
```

Comment: @rnorouzian after reading with `read.table` i.e. `out <- read.table(...); names(out)[6] <- "Method"`

Comment: @rnorouzian updated the post.  it is based on the pattern of neighbouring digits

Comment: @rnorouzian the issue with that is the columns were not created before you read and the headers and the column values can mismatch because of multiple spaces. e.g.  if you have a column value like `"New York County Growth Rate"`, there are 5 words, while your column name can be a single word `'Description`'

Comment: Arun, do you happen to know [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146127/matrix-dropping-the-column-names-inconsistently-in-r)?